# INFO log messages is turned off

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

In the beginning, the log messages will show up when spring boot app startups, but after adding another dependency project in Java build path, the INFO logs don't show up anymore. The IDE used is spring tool suite 4.
Is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Which dependency? Please show your code (your `pom.xml` in this case).

Comment: <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <modules>
  <module>../guppylibrary</module>
 </modules>

Comment: This is the project module I added